# Error:Could not find class 'com.yupptv.Activity.MainActivity', referenced from method com.yupptv.Activity.HomeActivity$2.onItemClick

Tags: blackberry-10

How to solve this error and fix these issues?

Could not find class 'com.yupptv.Activity.MainActivity', referenced from method com.yupptv.Activity.HomeActivity$2.onItemClick

Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform

```
enter code here
```

04-22 14:23:32.515: D/dalvikvm(142413927): Late-enabling CheckJNI
http://api.yupptv.com/androidservice.svc/getmenu?vapi=jILiMUI&vdevid=11&vboxno=&vuserid=0
04-22 14:24:50.318: W/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
04-22 14:24:50.321: W/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
04-22 14:24:50.322: I/dalvikvm(142413927): Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance, referenced from method com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction
04-22 14:24:50.322: W/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: unable to resolve static method 904: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
04-22 14:24:50.322: D/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0009
04-22 14:24:50.770: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/yupptv/Activity/BaseActivity; (182)
04-22 14:24:50.771: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Link of class 'Lcom/yupptv/Activity/BaseActivity;' failed
04-22 14:24:50.772: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity; (1738)
04-22 14:24:50.772: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Link of class 'Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity;' failed
04-22 14:24:50.773: E/dalvikvm(142413927): Could not find class 'com.yupptv.Activity.MainActivity', referenced from method com.yupptv.Activity.HomeActivity$2.onItemClick
04-22 14:24:50.773: W/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1824 (Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity;) in Lcom/yupptv/Activity/HomeActivity$2;
04-22 14:24:50.773: D/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x004e
04-22 14:24:50.774: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/yupptv/Activity/BaseActivity; (182)
04-22 14:24:50.774: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Link of class 'Lcom/yupptv/Activity/BaseActivity;' failed
04-22 14:24:50.774: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity; (1738)
04-22 14:24:50.774: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Link of class 'Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity;' failed
04-22 14:24:50.775: E/dalvikvm(142413927): Could not find class 'com.yupptv.Activity.MainActivity', referenced from method com.yupptv.Activity.HomeActivity$2.onItemClick
04-22 14:24:50.775: W/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1824 (Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity;) in Lcom/yupptv/Activity/HomeActivity$2;
04-22 14:24:50.775: D/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x008b
04-22 14:24:50.776: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/yupptv/Activity/BaseActivity; (182)
04-22 14:24:50.776: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Link of class 'Lcom/yupptv/Activity/BaseActivity;' failed
04-22 14:24:50.776: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity; (1738)
04-22 14:24:50.776: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Link of class 'Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity;' failed
04-22 14:24:50.777: E/dalvikvm(142413927): Could not find class 'com.yupptv.Activity.MainActivity', referenced from method com.yupptv.Activity.HomeActivity$2.onItemClick
04-22 14:24:50.777: W/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1824 (Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity;) in Lcom/yupptv/Activity/HomeActivity$2;
04-22 14:24:50.777: D/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x00c8
04-22 14:24:50.778: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/yupptv/Activity/BaseActivity; (182)
04-22 14:24:50.778: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Link of class 'Lcom/yupptv/Activity/BaseActivity;' failed
04-22 14:24:50.779: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity; (1738)
04-22 14:24:50.779: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Link of class 'Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity;' failed
04-22 14:24:50.779: E/dalvikvm(142413927): Could not find class 'com.yupptv.Activity.MainActivity', referenced from method com.yupptv.Activity.HomeActivity$2.onItemClick
04-22 14:24:50.779: W/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1824 (Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity;) in Lcom/yupptv/Activity/HomeActivity$2;
04-22 14:24:50.779: D/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0105
04-22 14:24:50.782: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/yupptv/Activity/BaseActivity; (182)
04-22 14:24:50.782: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Link of class 'Lcom/yupptv/Activity/BaseActivity;' failed
04-22 14:24:50.782: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity; (1738)
04-22 14:24:50.782: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Link of class 'Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity;' failed
04-22 14:24:50.782: E/dalvikvm(142413927): Could not find class 'com.yupptv.Activity.MainActivity', referenced from method com.yupptv.Activity.HomeActivity$2.onItemClick
04-22 14:24:50.782: W/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1824 (Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity;) in Lcom/yupptv/Activity/HomeActivity$2;
04-22 14:24:50.782: D/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0143
04-22 14:24:50.786: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/yupptv/Activity/BaseActivity; (182)
04-22 14:24:50.786: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Link of class 'Lcom/yupptv/Activity/BaseActivity;' failed
04-22 14:24:50.788: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity; (1738)
04-22 14:24:50.788: W/dalvikvm(142413927): Link of class 'Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity;' failed
04-22 14:24:50.788: E/dalvikvm(142413927): Could not find class 'com.yupptv.Activity.MainActivity', referenced from method com.yupptv.Activity.HomeActivity$2.onItemClick
04-22 14:24:50.788: W/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1824 (Lcom/yupptv/Activity/MainActivity;) in Lcom/yupptv/Activity/HomeActivity$2;
04-22 14:24:50.788: D/dalvikvm(142413927): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0181
04-22 14:24:51.257: I/dalvikvm(142413927): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libwebcore.so)
04-22 14:24:51.982: E/ActivityThread(142413927): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
04-22 14:24:52.078: E/hash keyHomeactivity+++++(142413927): 8VdX7V3djX9WELpiswXcQE6MqgI=
04-22 14:24:52.084: I/Ads(142413927): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("84DD8B9420B398E7FB80E5D5BEA297F0");
04-22 14:24:52.303: W/FlurryAgent(142413927): Start session
04-22 14:24:52.338: D/dalvikvm(142413927): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads91405468.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
04-22 14:24:52.817: E/onstart(142413927): homeactivity
04-22 14:24:52.820: E/*****(142413927): onresume
04-22 14:24:52.826: W/System.err(142413927): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 14:24:52.830: W/System.err(142413927):    at com.yupptv.Activity.HomeActivity.onResume(HomeActivity.java:475)
04-22 14:24:52.830: W/System.err(142413927):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
04-22 14:24:52.830: W/System.err(142413927):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5230)
04-22 14:24:52.834: W/System.err(142413927):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
04-22 14:24:52.834: W/System.err(142413927):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
04-22 14:24:52.835: W/System.err(142413927):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
04-22 14:24:52.835: W/System.err(142413927):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-22 14:24:52.835: W/System.err(142413927):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-22 14:24:52.835: W/System.err(142413927):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 14:24:52.835: W/System.err(142413927):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 14:24:52.835: W/System.err(142413927):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5056)
04-22 14:24:52.836: W/System.err(142413927):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 14:24:52.838: W/System.err(142413927):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 14:24:52.838: W/System.err(142413927):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:840)
04-22 14:24:52.839: W/System.err(142413927):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
04-22 14:24:52.839: W/System.err(142413927):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 14:24:52.901: D/dalvikvm(142413927): DexOpt: --- END 'ads91405468.jar' (success) ---
04-22 14:24:52.901: D/dalvikvm(142413927): DEX prep '/data/data/com.tru/cache/ads91405468.jar': unzip in 4ms, rewrite 563ms
04-22 14:24:52.961: I/dalvikvm(142413927): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
04-22 14:24:52.961: I/dalvikvm(142413927): Total arena pages for JIT: 12
04-22 14:24:52.962: I/dalvikvm(142413927): Total arena pages for JIT: 13
04-22 14:24:52.963: I/dalvikvm(142413927): Total arena pages for JIT: 14
04-22 14:24:52.963: I/dalvikvm(142413927): Total arena pages for JIT: 15
04-22 14:24:52.963: I/dalvikvm(142413927): Total arena pages for JIT: 16
04-22 14:24:52.964: I/dalvikvm(142413927): Total arena pages for JIT: 17
04-22 14:24:52.964: I/Choreographer(142413927): Skipped 158 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-22 14:24:53.431: I/Ads(142413927): adRequestUrlHtml: AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"5216932007707263950","u_sd":2,"seq_num":"1","slotname":"/28418187/YuppTVAndroidHome","u_w":360,"msid":"com.tru","cap":"a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","ms":"32G8GC1UGhVr8rT1tjv4qfKtjoYTkPjGT-dMi8z9XPODm5pEJ9HISgC3b3Di3r18o3uqrqkxbDjE-DK8PpggrD3iF_xXd-1hI_zShhDEUaN8jHkf6uqH-A2FE4DXidD8m6heMRcQjT3ISO34mJnJJhbPj55cOKvLZ9HuF6PjBapmuSaTGEzCBw2av4itWc9P15Wdv-K4NX64-L0ZK8M-vh78A6ElsITx6PWYjQIi-iXvf0oZdZcVaXQh18dWZsj8Risp5Lh-22GV9Mw9aFzXtD2Y8QYakhwhUrIkDNS3TzNmXJY5hZGMb-syBYWWL1Ud3SKbQjgh6y3yj-Uk31mFqQ","isu":"84DD8B9420B398E7FB80E5D5BEA297F0","bas_off":0,"format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"1112651.android.com.tru","hl":"en","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":1,"y":620,"x":0,"width":720},"gnt":0,"u_h":310,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0,"u_audio":3});
04-22 14:24:54.023: D/dalvikvm(142413927): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3488K, 22% free 13293K/17016K, paused 22ms+5ms, total 197ms
04-22 14:24:54.034: D/webviewglue(142413927): nativeDestroy view: 7e905980
04-22 14:24:54.994: W/FlurryAgent(142413927): FlurryDataSender: report df8ac65c-21fb-47c6-87b8-3e147ae75215 sent. HTTP response: 200 : OK
04-22 14:24:55.239: E/mtoken(142413927): 3
04-22 14:24:55.248: E/getmenu devekey*******(142413927): CXZ5YYa00kiIasQxGqGjBKRefmVpesxRcvrusGos2o4A9tschfjZszit2lPn25h5
04-22 14:24:55.253: E/location*******(142413927): IN
04-22 14:24:55.258: E/signinnode*******(142413927): 0
04-22 14:24:55.265: E/location*******(142413927): http://www.yupptv.com/samsung/SearchUrl.aspx
04-22 14:24:55.269: E/smovieitems*******(142413927): livehttp://www.yupptv.com/samsung/amzonsearchindia.aspx?skey=DATA&stype=LIVE
04-22 14:24:55.274: E/smovieitems*******(142413927): vodshttp://www.yupptv.com/samsung/amzonsearchindia.aspx?skey=DATA&stype=VOD
04-22 14:24:55.278: E/smovieitems*******(142413927): movieshttp://www.yupptv.com/samsung/amzonsearchindia.aspx?skey=DATA&stype=MOVIE
04-22 14:24:55.283: E/smovieitems*******(142413927): eventshttp://www.yupptv.com/samsung/amzonsearchindia.aspx?skey=DATA&stype=EVENTS
[com.yupptv.bean.SubCategories@7b838c40, com.yupptv.bean.SubCategories@7b839148]
04-22 14:24:55.396: E/Hello size............Data(142413927): [com.yupptv.bean.SubCategories@7b83a588, com.yupptv.bean.SubCategories@7b83a738]
04-22 14:24:55.397: E/Hello size............Data(142413927): [com.yupptv.bean.SubCategories@7b83b3b8, com.yupptv.bean.SubCategories@7b83b560, com.yupptv.bean.SubCategories@7b83ba20, com.yupptv.bean.SubCategories@7b83cab0]

04-22 14:24:55.488: E/catgories(142413927): ChangeLanguage
04-22 14:24:55.492: E/ifsignin(142413927): homeactivity0

04-22 14:24:55.509: E/catgories(142413927): ChangeLanguage
04-22 14:24:55.515: E/ifsignin(142413927): homeactivity0
04-22 14:24:55.515: E/catgories size(142413927): 5
04-22 14:24:55.532: E/catgories(142413927): ChangeLanguage
04-22 14:24:55.742: I/Ads(142413927): Received ad url: http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net:80/gampad/ads?u_sd=2&seq_num=1&u_w=360&msid=com.tru&cap=a&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&ms=32G8GC1UGhVr8rT1tjv4qfKtjoYTkPjGT-dMi8z9XPODm5pEJ9HISgC3b3Di3r18o3uqrqkxbDjE-DK8PpggrD3iF_xXd-1hI_zShhDEUaN8jHkf6uqH-A2FE4DXidD8m6heMRcQjT3ISO34mJnJJhbPj55cOKvLZ9HuF6PjBapmuSaTGEzCBw2av4itWc9P15Wdv-K4NX64-L0ZK8M-vh78A6ElsITx6PWYjQIi-iXvf0oZdZcVaXQh18dWZsj8Risp5Lh-22GV9Mw9aFzXtD2Y8QYakhwhUrIkDNS3TzNmXJY5hZGMb-syBYWWL1Ud3SKbQjgh6y3yj-Uk31mFqQ&bas_off=0&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&net=wi&hl=en&gnt=0&u_h=310&bas_on=0&u_audio=3&imbf=%40installed_markets%40&u_so=l&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=330&url=1112651.android.com.tru.adsenseformobileapps.com&gdfp_req=1&markup=html&m_ast=afmajs&impl=ifr&correlator=2596240460487539&iu=%2F28418187%2FYuppTVAndroidHome&sz=320x50&gsb=wi&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&eid=46621031&jsv=83&urll=892" type: "xfp" afmaNotifyDt: "null" activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
04-22 14:24:55.780: I/Ads(142413927): Ad url modified to http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net:80/gampad/ads?u_sd=2&seq_num=1&u_w=360&msid=com.tru&cap=a&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&ms=32G8GC1UGhVr8rT1tjv4qfKtjoYTkPjGT-dMi8z9XPODm5pEJ9HISgC3b3Di3r18o3uqrqkxbDjE-DK8PpggrD3iF_xXd-1hI_zShhDEUaN8jHkf6uqH-A2FE4DXidD8m6heMRcQjT3ISO34mJnJJhbPj55cOKvLZ9HuF6PjBapmuSaTGEzCBw2av4itWc9P15Wdv-K4NX64-L0ZK8M-vh78A6ElsITx6PWYjQIi-iXvf0oZdZcVaXQh18dWZsj8Risp5Lh-22GV9Mw9aFzXtD2Y8QYakhwhUrIkDNS3TzNmXJY5hZGMb-syBYWWL1Ud3SKbQjgh6y3yj-Uk31mFqQ&bas_off=0&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&net=wi&hl=en&gnt=0&u_h=310&bas_on=0&u_audio=3&imbf=88008&u_so=l&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=330&url=1112651.android.com.tru.adsenseformobileapps.com&gdfp_req=1&markup=html&m_ast=afmajs&impl=ifr&correlator=2596240460487539&iu=%2F28418187%2FYuppTVAndroidHome&sz=320x50&gsb=wi&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&eid=46621031&jsv=83&urll=892
04-22 14:24:55.781: I/Ads(142413927): Request scenario: Online server request.
04-22 14:24:55.834: I/Ads(142413927): Received log message: <"string": " You are using version 6.4.1 of the AdMob SDK which is non-compliant with the Google Play Ad Policy (http://goo.gl/6OZelH). On August 1st, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting updates to apps using this SDK. Upgrade to Google Play services now to avoid this deadline.", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
04-22 14:24:56.311: D/dalvikvm(142413927): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5795K, 46% free 9224K/17016K, paused 10ms+5ms, total 54ms
04-22 14:24:56.586: W/Ads(142413927): adSize was expected to be null in AdLoader.
04-22 14:24:58.686: D/webviewglue(142413927): nativeDestroy view: 7e9058f0
04-22 14:24:58.717: I/Ads(142413927): onReceiveAd()
04-22 14:24:58.801: D/dalvikvm(142413927): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 389K, 47% free 9182K/17016K, paused 59ms, total 59ms
04-22 14:24:58.931: D/TilesManager(142413927): Starting TG #0, 77f24628
04-22 14:25:56.565: I/Ads(142413927): Refreshing ad.
04-22 14:25:56.595: E/ActivityThread(142413927): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
04-22 14:25:56.676: I/Ads(142413927): adRequestUrlHtml: AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":1,"session_id":"5216932007707263950","seq_num":"2","slotname":"/28418187/YuppTVAndroidHome","u_w":360,"msid":"com.tru","cap":"a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","prnl":4502,"bas_off":0,"imbf":"88008","net":"wi","app_name":"1112651.android.com.tru","hl":"en","gnt":0,"u_audio":3,"u_sd":2,"ms":"Vc90wXM25pnH4RRYhucw54lkSfpWNZPKZzUlWDhYJCuhWAd1UNqquqat2KvswA2zO8l2h8llRo5vFv__smnqp03vMT7s-gcjtR7KvdaKyBpW29d2y38jn7lS3o3XGnZHwRSWX3W8tZoAyj2GBvo7rWYjn75V0xBKhzt5nf65eMlNf_WF7Y4Ki0FrksYlxng0602QI78J7Fim_sgYPlJRS_UojSoOVSaLT7STLyhWM_FZFH11SLJU3E9jgCnu-hlwZdacBic_1wA9UZiFg2Y8hVE8bD0S8RBCbUbJGUFC0v2ED2NeRFgVfVQrBGmo8uoArlAeELjXbiXFZaNtwLTfgQ","isu":"84DD8B9420B398E7FB80E5D5BEA297F0","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":100,"visible":1,"y":520,"x":0,"width":720},"u_h":310,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":64553,"prl":6632});
04-22 14:25:56.873: I/Ads(142413927): Received ad url: http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net:80/gampad/ads?seq_num=2&u_w=360&msid=com.tru&cap=a&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&prnl=4502&bas_off=0&imbf=88008&net=wi&hl=en&gnt=0&u_audio=3&u_sd=2&ms=Vc90wXM25pnH4RRYhucw54lkSfpWNZPKZzUlWDhYJCuhWAd1UNqquqat2KvswA2zO8l2h8llRo5vFv__smnqp03vMT7s-gcjtR7KvdaKyBpW29d2y38jn7lS3o3XGnZHwRSWX3W8tZoAyj2GBvo7rWYjn75V0xBKhzt5nf65eMlNf_WF7Y4Ki0FrksYlxng0602QI78J7Fim_sgYPlJRS_UojSoOVSaLT7STLyhWM_FZFH11SLJU3E9jgCnu-hlwZdacBic_1wA9UZiFg2Y8hVE8bD0S8RBCbUbJGUFC0v2ED2NeRFgVfVQrBGmo8uoArlAeELjXbiXFZaNtwLTfgQ&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&u_h=310&bas_on=0&u_so=l&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=330&url=1112651.android.com.tru.adsenseformobileapps.com&gdfp_req=1&markup=html&m_ast=afmajs&impl=ifr&correlator=3242036402381292&iu=%2F28418187%2FYuppTVAndroidHome&sz=320x50&gsb=wi&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&eid=46621031&jsv=83&urll=884" type: "xfp" afmaNotifyDt: "null" activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
04-22 14:25:56.875: I/Ads(142413927): Request scenario: Online server request.
04-22 14:25:57.006: I/Ads(142413927): Received log message: <"string": " You are using version 6.4.1 of the AdMob SDK which is non-compliant with the Google Play Ad Policy (http://goo.gl/6OZelH). On August 1st, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting updates to apps using this SDK. Upgrade to Google Play services now to avoid this deadline.", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
04-22 14:25:57.029: D/dalvikvm(142413927): GC_CONCURRENT freed 133K, 45% free 9455K/17016K, paused 7ms+3ms, total 55ms
04-22 14:25:57.723: W/Ads(142413927): adSize was expected to be null in AdLoader.
04-22 14:25:58.499: D/webviewglue(142413927): nativeDestroy view: 77c169f0
04-22 14:25:58.516: I/Ads(142413927): onReceiveAd()
04-22 14:26:34.695: D/dalvikvm(142413927): GC_CONCURRENT freed 382K, 45% free 9457K/17016K, paused 11ms+6ms, total 59ms
04-22 14:26:56.664: I/Ads(142413927): Refreshing ad.
04-22 14:26:56.688: E/ActivityThread(142413927): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform

while running an android app on BlackBerry 10 device.

I have ported a android App to BB 10 App.

Please solve it

Comment: I think it's trying to find Google Plus, which Google did not make available for BlackBerry 10. Maybe find a workaround

Comment: But there is GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar added already to libs folder of my project and already added to the projects build path.

Comment: And Google play services SDK is also installed in the sdk manager

Comment: It can be in SDK manager, and it will work on an Android device. But BlackBerry 10 devices don't have Google Play services, so it can't work